# Page re-routing based on URL before the page loads

Tags: parsing, redirect, http-status-code-301, directory

What I am trying to do is make a system where users can type basic information into the address bar in the form of directories

i.e:

```
domainname.com/country/state/city/
```

and then be "re-routed" to specific information on a universal page with URL variables

i.e:

```
domainname.com/Canada/BritishColumbia/Squamish  =>  domainname.com/wall.php?country=canada&state=britishcolumbia&city=squamish
```

I know this could be accomplished by creating actual directories for each city that has been registered and then having an index.php inside that directory with a 301 redirect but that seems like a super-inefficient, messy last resort.

How can I parse the URL before the page loads and then redirect to wall.php with the specific URL variables? I can't seem to find any tutorials or anything else relevant.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [url rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).